# How to find Total of sum of rows in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get all rows from table. I could do that job properly. But the problem comes when I put each row values as percentage and tried to sum the percentage. For example, I am using the following query to output all the rows:

```
SELECT SUM( Mark_score ) / SUM( Full_mark ) *50 AS Score
FROM nuexam
WHERE regd = '22'
GROUP BY subject
```

With the above query I got the following output:

[image: Query Output]

I want to sum total of this `Score`. This is so far what I could output. Any help is very much appreciated. I will also welcome the php solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply running a nested query should work:

```
SELECT SUM(s) as Score
FROM (SELECT SUM( Mark_score ) / SUM( Full_mark ) *50 AS s
    FROM nuexam
    WHERE regd = '22'
    GROUP BY subject) table
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Something like this is coming:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SUM( Mark_score ) / SUM( Full_mark ) *50 AS s FROM nuexam WHERE regd = '' at line 2

Comment: Ah, sorry, correcting my answer now! Just forgot the `SELECT`

Comment: thanks again, this is still coming: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias...

Comment: Does a sub-query alias of "table" actually work, given that it is a reserved word?

Comment: You might have to escape it with a backtick. I usually use backticks anyhow when I do write raw SQL (to prevent clashes; generally use ORMs) so I'm not exactly sure.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the individual scores *along with* the total, then use `with rollup`.  The proper way for your data would be:

```
select coalesce(subject, 'Total'), sum(t.Score)
from (SELECT subject, SUM( Mark_score ) / SUM( Full_mark ) *50 AS Score
      FROM nuexam
      WHERE regd = '22'
      GROUP BY subject
     ) t
group by subject with rollup;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have been trying to achieve...Thanks a million.

Answer (score 2):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a505a/4

```
select sum(t.Score) from 
(SELECT SUM( Mark_score ) / SUM( Full_mark ) *50 AS Score
FROM nuexam
WHERE regd = '22'
GROUP BY subject ) t
```